# Discord.js read Embd by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a System who read a embed by id and edit it. I want to copy the Description from the old Embed but it gives a error

Code:

```
            message.delete();
            if(message.author.id === "697786816379617320") {
               if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send({ content: "Keine Message ID" });
    
                else if(args[0]) {
                  const VorschlagEmbedOriginal = message.embeds[0];
                    const VorschlagAbgelehnt = new Discord.MessageEmbed(VorschlagEmbedOriginal)
                    .setTitle("» :x: - VORSCHLAG ABGELEHNT")
                    .setDescription(VorschlagEmbedOriginal.description)
                    .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/kgcY5rF.png")
                    .setColor('#ff0000');
                    
                    
                    message.channel.messages.fetch({around: args[1], limit: 1})
                     .then(msg => {
                         const fetchedMsg = msg.first();
                         fetchedMsg.edit({ embeds: [VorschlagAbgelehnt] });
                    });
                }
            }
            else return;
            }`
```

Comment: What's the error you get when you run the code?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading „description“)

Comment: I think you can remove the `.setDescription` line in the new embed since if you don't provide any description, it will take the old one

Comment: It gives me nothing, its only send the title and thumbnail from the new embed

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that this message is in the same channel that the command is being sent in this should help. You were defining the embed before it was even fetched. First you need to fetch the message then the client will have access to the message embed.

```js
message.delete();
if (message.author.id === "697786816379617320") {
    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send({
        content: "Keine Message ID"
    });

    if (args[0]) {
        message.channel.messages.fetch(args[1])
            .then(msg => {
                const VorschlagAbgelehnt = new MessageEmbed(msg.embeds[0])
                    .setTitle("» :x: - VORSCHLAG ABGELEHNT")
                    .setDescription(`${msg.embeds[0].description}`)
                    .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/kgcY5rF.png")
                    .setColor('#ff0000');

                msg.edit({
                    embeds: [VorschlagAbgelehnt]
                });
            });
    }
} else return;
```